# Subscribing to file check ins with tfs 2010 alerts

Tags: tfs

I am trying to setup alerts to the team when a specific file is checked into TFS, have have found some info on this using tfs 2008, which leads me to believe the following filter should work:

'Artifacts/Artifact[starts-with(@ServerItem, $/Matrix/Dev/Matrix/Applications/Matrix.UI/Web.Config)]' <> NULL

But this just give me an Invalid Token error, any ideas how i get this working in 2010?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With installed [Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f), right-click in Team Explorer on the upmost node (the icon for the TeamCollection) & open "Alerts Explorer".
Generate a new CheckIn alert:
[image]

 now set the source control pathto the files you 're interested in:
[image]

This generated a Filter Expression = `'Artifacts/Artifact[starts-with(translate(@ServerItem, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), "$/foo/bar.cs")]' <> null`

Comment: I am probably being totaly stupid, but i cant see where to launch Alert Explorer, if i right click the team project i can only see the Project Alerts... menu entry fom the August power tools (which i has installed before i installed the December release).

Comment: Ok, you have to right click the project collection, not the project.

Comment: Exactly! Sorry for not making it clear enough - I'm editing the answer.